# Confusing with upgrading ORMLite schema

Tags: android, ormlite

I've added a column(`description`) to my table `account`. I also read [this guild](http://ormlite.com/javadoc/ormlite-core/doc-files/ormlite_4.html#Upgrading-Schema) to upgrade my database. However, I had a bit confusing of what is `getHelper()` method in this code:

```
Dao<Account, Integer> dao = getHelper().getAccountDao();
// change the table to add a new column named "description" 
dao.executeRaw("ALTER TABLE `account` ADD COLUMN description INTEGER;");
```

and where did it come from? I didn't see `getHelper()` was declared in my `DatabaseHelper` class. Can someone help me?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You should have a class extending `OrmLiteSqliteOpenHelper` where you create the tables (in `onCreate`) and update them (in `onUpgrade`):

```
public class DatabaseHelper extends OrmLiteSqliteOpenHelper {

    public DatabaseHelper(Context context) {
        super(context, "database.db", null, 1);
    }

    @Override
    public void onCreate(SQLiteDatabase database, ConnectionSource connectionSource) {
        try {
           TableUtils.createTable(connectionSource, Account.class);
        } catch (SQLException e) {
            throw new RuntimeException("Error when create database tables", e);
        }
    }

    @Override
    public void onUpgrade(SQLiteDatabase database, ConnectionSource connectionSource, int oldVersion, int newVersion) {
        database.execSQL("ALTER TABLE `account` ADD COLUMN description INTEGER;");

        //same as:
        //AccountDAO dao = getDao(Acount.class);
        //dao.executeRaw("ALTER TABLE 'account' ADD COLUMN description INTEGER;");
    }
}
```

> `OrmLiteBaseListActivity`, `OrmLiteBaseService` and
>   `OrmLiteBaseTabActivity` provide a method `getHelper` to access the
>   database helper whenever it is needed and will automatically create
>   the helper in the onCreate() method and release it in the onDestroy()
>   method.

Furthermore, if you are using classes above, you should have something like this:

```
public class MyACtivity extends OrmLiteBaseActivity<DatabaseHelper> {

    //In this class, you can call getHelper() to obtain the DatabaseHelper instance 

}
```

Comment: Thank you for your detail answer, as from your code `database.execSQL("ALTER TABLE 'account' ADD COLUMN description INTEGER;");` is equal to `Dao<Account, Integer> dao = getHelper().getAccountDao();
// change the table to add a new column named "description" 
dao.executeRaw("ALTER TABLE 'account' ADD COLUMN description INTEGER;");`?

Comment: I have edited the aswer. Now, you can see how get the dao inside DatabaseHelper class.

Comment: I ran your code, but still cannot add `description` column to table. The log said: `Unknown field 'description' from the Android sqlite cursor`, something wrong here?

Comment: Have you added the new field `description` to the Acount table mapping?

Comment: Yes I have: `@DatabaseField
    private Integer description;` in Account table

Comment: `@DatabaseField(columnName = "description") private Integer description;` Don't forget the col name.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/94181/discussion-between-bigdestroyer-and-dinhngochien).